# What if the moderator was unreasonable and blocked me?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I asked a questions on superuser, it was technical question and I added some more details why I want to block a certain youtube channel.

instead of getting technical answers, I got parental advises !!!

anyway, I asked everyone to focus on the technical problem and leave the parental advises.

Will... the people who commented the parental advice were one of the high score users and apparently did not like my comments to focus on the technical aspect of the question and let me take care of my kids by my self.

the consequences for that comment, was banning me from posting any questions!.

I believe this is bias and not fair.

Can someone fair review the question and see if I deserve to be banned just for one question which i still believe it is relevant question?

my question is here

[How can I block the a YouTube channel?](https://superuser.com/questions/1438280/how-can-i-block-the-a-youtube-channel)

Comment: A moderator didn't block you. Five regular uses voted to close your question. If you are currently blocked from asking further questions, it is the system that is blocking you and it didn't happen from just one question. The system would be blocking you based on question history. If you are currently banned from asking questions by the system, a moderator is unable to lift the ban.

Comment: Nobody who voted to close your question even submitted a comment.  It is not possible to be question banned due to a single bad question.  So the only explanation, for your question ban is that you have a history of asking questions, that have been downvoted and were eventually deleted.

Answer (score 12):

Its not one question - you have about 4 deleted questions as well, automatically deleted because they are zero or negative scored and have no answer.

Question bans are *automatic*. Mods can't question ban you or lift it, though you get a chance after 6 months to post a question.

While there *are* ways to appeal a moderator decision, literally zero moderators are involved in what happened.

Now you *could* possibly have flagged the comments - but at this point, I'd totally suggest reviewing your question and talk more about your network and what you want.

I'm a reasonable moderator though - I'd be happy to edit your question, stuff some keywords that would be helpful, and get rid of a few others, and let the community decide if its worthy to reopen.